# Creating 2 occurrence predicates out of another predicate based on min/max number of other index in the original predicate

Tags: clingo

I have the following input in Clingo:

```
val(a,2,3).
val(a,4,5).
val(b,0,6).
val(b,1,2).
```

the required is to have two predicates representing the first and second occurrence of each letter where the first one is the minimum number of the third index of `val` (case 1: only based on min of 3rd index), in case they are the same, then based on minimum number of the second index (case 2: both conditions).

Note that the maximum number of occurrences for each letter is 2.

The expected results is having two predicates with these values (only for this case, as sometimes the input is different):

```
first(a,2,3), first(b,1,2), second(a,4,5), second(b,0,6)
```

I tried the following code for case 1:

```
val(X,Y,W) :- val(X,Y,W).

first(X,Y,Z) :- val(X,Y,Z), not val(X,Y',Z'), Z'>Z,Y'!=Y.
second(X,Y,Z) :- val(X,Y,Z), not first(X,_,_).
```

but an error messages showed saying that `Z'` and `Y'` are unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Z'` and `Y'` are unsafe because they do not appear in any positive predicate.

Moreover:

- `val(X,Y,W) :- val(X,Y,W).` is a tautology and, therefore, it is useless;
- it is not clear to me why you are imposing that `Y'!=Y`;
- `not first(X,_,_)` is wrong, since it is checking that there doesn't exist ANY predicate `first` with variable `X` in the first argument (but this should always happen).

If I've correctly understood your requirements, this should be the correct implementation:

```
first(X,Y,Z) :- val(X,Y,Z), val(X,Y',Z'), Z'>Z .       % case 1
first(X,Y,Z) :- val(X,Y,Z), val(X,Y',Z'), Z'=Z, Y'>Y . % case 2
second(X,Y,Z) :- val(X,Y,Z), not first(X,Y,Z) .
```